# adding a gradient background with three colors to the Scaffold widget

Tags: flutter, dart

My result -

[image]

What I expected -

[image]

I don't have an idea how to fix this, there is my code

I did -

- Set the background color of Scaffold to transparent
- use the Container widget and add LinearGradient

  ```
  Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              Color.fromRGBO(31, 16, 80, 1),
              Color.fromRGBO(13, 4, 42, 1),
              Color.fromRGBO(42, 28, 81, 1),
            ],
            stops: [
              0.1,
              0.4,
              0.9,
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          ),
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // Your content widgets go here
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  ```

Comment: just tried on `dartpad` , the code work as expected result.
 have you try it on real device? probably the issue come from the emulator

Answer (score 0):

```
return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(13, 4, 42, 1),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
           
            Positioned(
                top: -(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75),
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: Transform.scale(
                    scale: 1.5,
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(31, 16, 80, 1),
                          blurRadius: 50,
                          spreadRadius: 3)
                    ], shape: BoxShape.circle),
                  ),
                )),
            Positioned(
              bottom: -(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95),
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Transform.scale(
                scale: 1.5,
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(42, 28, 81, 1),
                        blurRadius: 50,
                        spreadRadius: 3)
                  ], shape: BoxShape.circle),
                ),
              ),
            ),
             Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
               child: Column()
              )
            ),
          ],
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  body: Container(
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
     gradient: LinearGradient(
       colors: [
         Color.fromRGBO(68, 20, 208, 1.0),
         Color.fromRGBO(13, 4, 42, 1),
         Color.fromRGBO(68, 20, 208, 1.0),
       ],
   
       begin: Alignment.topCenter,
       end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
     ),
   ),
   child: SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Column(
       children: [
         // Your content widgets go here
       ],
     ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Output

[image]